Issue with slow island loading in Deno fresh application
application is here
I have a Deno Fresh app, it runs fine for the most part but there is an issue on load in a browser that hasn't cached anything, clicking the about button doesn't work on the first click but does on the second if you click another in between.
There is also an issue on my android phone where it stutters when scrolling down to the about section as the animation loads.
Any help would be amazing, the repo is here but the island code for navigation and about look as follows:
import { Links, Icons } from "@/components/layout/Navigation.tsx";
import { useSignal } from "@preact/signals";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "preact/hooks";

export default function Navigation() {
  const isHidden = useSignal<boolean>(false);
  const prevPosition = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const position = globalThis.window.scrollY;
      const threshold = 300;

      if (
        position > threshold &&
        position < prevPosition.current
      ) {
        isHidden.value = false;
      } else if (position > threshold) {
        isHidden.value = true;
      } else {
        isHidden.value = false;
      }

      prevPosition.current = position;
    };

    self.window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      self.window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  });

  return (
    <header
      class={`
        grid sticky top-1 z-10 place-items-center w-screen transition-transform duration-300
        ${isHidden.value && "-translate-y-[110%]"}
      `}
    >
      <nav class="flex justify-between items-center px-4 py-2 space-x-4 bg-black rounded-full border-2 max-w-60 border-neutral-800">
        <Links />
        <Icons />
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

import { useSignal } from "@preact/signals";
import IconBrandGit from "https://deno.land/x/tabler_icons_tsx@0.0.5/tsx/brand-git.tsx";
import IconBrandNextjs from "https://deno.land/x/tabler_icons_tsx@0.0.5/tsx/brand-nextjs.tsx";
import IconBrandPython from "https://deno.land/x/tabler_icons_tsx@0.0.5/tsx/brand-python.tsx";
import IconBrandReact from "https://deno.land/x/tabler_icons_tsx@0.0.5/tsx/brand-react.tsx";
import IconBrandTailwind from "https://deno.land/x/tabler_icons_tsx@0.0.5/tsx/brand-tailwind.tsx";
import IconBrandTypescript from "https://deno.land/x/tabler_icons_tsx@0.0.5/tsx/brand-typescript.tsx";
import IconTerminal2 from "https://deno.land/x/tabler_icons_tsx@0.0.5/tsx/terminal-2.tsx";
import { useEffect } from "preact/hooks"; // Import useEffect for side effects

export default function Skills() {
  const active = useSignal<string | null>(null);
  const flashIcons = useSignal<boolean>(false);
  const animationPlayed = useSignal<boolean>(false);

  const skills = [
    { name: "Command Line", icon: IconTerminal2 },
    { name: "Git", icon: IconBrandGit },
    { name: "TypeScript", icon: IconBrandTypescript },
    { name: "React", icon: IconBrandReact },
    { name: "Next.js", icon: IconBrandNextjs },
    { name: "Tailwind", icon: IconBrandTailwind },
    { name: "Python", icon: IconBrandPython },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        let delay = 0;
        skills.forEach(({ name }) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            active.value = name;
          }, delay);
          delay += 140;
        });

        setTimeout(() => {
          active.value = null;
        }, delay += 110);

        setTimeout(() => {
          flashIcons.value = true;
        }, delay += 300);

        setTimeout(() => {
          flashIcons.value = false;
          active.value = skills[0].name;
          animationPlayed.value = true;
        }, delay + 300);

        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });

    observer.observe(document.getElementById("skills"));

    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section
      id="skills"
      class={`
        grid place-items-center gap-y-8
        ${flashIcons.value ? "text-blue-600 dark:text-neutral-300" : "text-neutral-600"}
      `}
    >
      <div class="flex items-center justify-center space-x-4">
        {skills.map(({ name, icon: Icon }) => (
          <Icon
            class={`
              cursor-pointer transition-colors duration-300 ease-in-out hover:text-blue-600 dark:hover:text-neutral-300
              ${active.value === name && "text-blue-600 dark:text-neutral-300"}
            `}
            onClick={() => (active.value = name)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <span
        class={`
          font-bold min-h-[28px] text-neutral-100 px-5 rounded-md bg-neutral-900 transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in
          ${animationPlayed.value === true ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"}
        `}
      >
        {active}
      </span>
    </section>
  );
}


Problem solved, I had some design quality images with 2500 plus resolution which were taking 5s to load and were interfering with the loading of the js.
I discovered this using the network tab of safari and seeing the images being slow to load.
